# Properties of materials _not_ dependent on fermi surface?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fermi-liquids

So I'm studying a second solid state physics course where we've covered calculating things like magnetic susceptibility, specific heat and resistivity by considering excitations of electrons around the material's fermi surface. I've also qualitatively studied fermi liquid theory.

From general reading, it seems like pretty much every property you can think of depends on the density of states at the fermi surface.

**Are there interesting cases or properties where this is not the case?**

The best I could come up was something like photoelectric emission, where I think the energies of your light could be comparable to the fermi energy..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and congrats on a cool first question that is waaaay over my head.